# Count similar entries in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, aggregate-functions

I have a table where a column for `grade` of students.
We have `A+` and `A` and `A-` and `B+` and B and `B-`.
Now we want to treat `A+` and `A` and `A-` all equal to `A`. So as `B+` and `B` and `B-` all equal to `B`.

How to write the expression to aggregate this?
The question is count how many `A` and `B?` `A+` and `A-` also mean `A.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of many:

```
SELECT left(grade, 1) as base_grade, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1
```

[`left()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) requires Postgres 9.1+. Else use `substring(grade, 1, 1)`.